# What are some statistical tests to perform from 8 samples (quantitative data) collected from 4 devices?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, modeling

I need advice on the best statistical analysis to perform for data I collected from 4 devices. Device A and B are of the same height and are taller than device C and D which are of the same height as well. Device A and C are soft and device B and D are hard. I recorded 8 quantitative data from each of the devices.

I want to know if height of the device and the softness of the device played a roll in the quantitative data collected and if yes, if it's statistically significant. Kindly advice me on any other test.

Comment: This is a two-way analysis of variance setting. Can you tell us more about the response?

Comment: Maybe do a one-factor ANOVA with four levels A, B, C. D to see if there are _any_ differences. Then, if so, do _pre-chosen_ contrasts to compare tall against short [coefficient vector $(1,1,-1,-1)]$ and soft against hard [vector $(1,-1,1,-1)].$